# Hibernate/JPQL: How to load parent with all childs based on query on a child

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

So we have a service with simplified these two entities

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
/* simplified*/

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ticket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Grant> grants = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Grant {
/* simplified*/

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = UsageGrant.FK_TICKET, nullable = false)
  private Ticket ticket;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "specialNumber", nullable = false)
  private Integer specialNumber;
}
```

I'd like to have a query that selects all tickets that contain a grant with a specific "specialNumber". The catch is that I want to have the ticket returned with all grants, not only the one matching. I tried it with

```
@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, String> {

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT ti FROM Ticket ti JOIN FETCH ti.grants g WHERE 
g.specialNumber = :specialNumber "
  )
  List<Ticket> findBySpecialNumberAndLoadAllGrantsOnTicket(
      @NotNull @Param("specialNumber") Integer specialNumber);
}
```

but this gives me just the matching one. Do I need to split it up into two queries? Criteria API also doesn't help, because RIGHT JOIN is also not supported there.

**Update**

I can achieve it with

```
SELECT g FROM Grant g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.ticket ti JOIN FETCH ti.grants WHERE g.specialNumber = :specialNumber
```

and accessing the ticket with g.getTicket(). The resulting query looks crazy and I'm not sure if this is a clever approach at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EntityGraph` for fetch `grants` and query using JPA method for select by `specialNumber`

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"grants"})
public List<Ticket> findByGrantsSpecialNumber(Integer specialNumber);
```

Or

You can use `@NamedEntityGraph`

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Ticket.Grants", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("grants") })
public class Ticket {
```

And

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Ticket.Grants", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
public List<Ticket> findByGrantsSpecialNumber(Integer specialNumber);
```

Comment: Not sure, this doesn't work for me. I still get the ticket via the grant but the other grants are not present, as it states that it is lazy loaded.

Comment: Just tried it out, doesn't work either. I just updated once more with the repo class. NEvertheless, I unfortunately can only post the simplified code for legal reasons. I also have Lombok in use for getters,setters, builder and equals and the structures are more complex, have more properties and relations but in the end it boils down to that.

Comment: @hecko84 Both solution worked for me, may be there is other implementation making problem. Check again I used `findByGrantsSpecialNumber` not `findByGrantSpecialNumber` (some version it makes problem)

Comment: Is there a difference in behavior if I specify the Query in the annotation? Maybe it's a dummy question, but I always feel like an idiot while working with JPA stumbling into issues :D

Comment: Actually `@Query` and `@EntityGraph` not working together thats why

Comment: Ok, then that's the explanation. Thanks a lot, I will see if I have a chance to restructure it as you proposed. So obviously my original approach is not going to work out?

Comment: No, as far I know.