# Jpa search by child property does not fetch all childs

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to find all parent entities by child id in one query, but in result i need to have parent with all child entites. Parent always have collection with only one child (with id from search). Condition shoud be 
applied to search but not to fetching the childs. Is it possible to do this in one query? Please help.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_hub")
public class UserHub {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hub", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserHubMember> hubMembers= new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity 
@Table(name = "user_hub_member")
public class UserHubMember implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    private string name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "\"hubId\"", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserHub hub;

    public UserHubMember () {
    }
}

 @Query("select uh from UserHub uh " +
                    "left join fetch uh.hubMembers hm" +
                    "where hm.id = :memberId"
    )
    List<UserHub> findAllByMemberId(Integer memberId);
```

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61616565/4207306

Comment: No, combination entity graph with jpql query give the same result

Comment: Use Entity graph with method name query, don't use JPQL

Comment: unfortunatly with method name query and entity graph result the same

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood your problem, you wanted to get parents:
(Having child entity which its id is equal specific id **along with** other child entities that do not meet the condition)

```
 @Query("select uh from UserHub uh left join fetch uh.hubMembers hm where hm.id = :memberId")
 List<UserHub> findAllByMemberId(Integer memberId);
```

There is a huge difference between using **JOIN** and **JOIN FETCH** in terms of JPA.

You can not achieve this with your query because you only fetch one child entity, you do not get others by explicitly specifying **join fetch**

You should do this instead:

```
@Query("select uh from UserHub uh join uh.hubMembers hm where hm.id = :memberId")
List<UserHub> findAllByMemberId(Integer memberId);
```

This will bring parents each having all child entities that meets your equality criteria

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, if I not use fetch I will get lazy initialization exception, becouse childs are not fectched at all...

Comment: If you manually close session using hibernate way and try to get child objects, you get exception but if you use @Transactional on Service class, it handles automatically.

Comment: Yes, but it will be another request to database for each parrent to get chailds. If we talk about  10 000 parents it is not looks good.